# bitwise operation class in Java

Tags: java, bit-manipulation

is there a class that makes bitwise operation easier ?
I need some methods that reads into integer the "value" of bits givem their offset and length (in a 32/64 bits byte array).

I can use the bit manipulations available with java but I rather use a debugged class.

Comment: What do you mean a debugged class?  If the bitwise operators didn't work, the Java Language would be broken.

Comment: I think "debugged" means "part of the standard library." E.g. tested, working, reliable.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at [BitSet](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html). And here is a [usage example](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Collections-Data-Structure/TheuseofBitSet.htm) that looks like it demonstrates code similar to what you need to do.

Answer (score 1):

Try `java.util.BitSet` or `java.math.BigInteger`.